# WordPress Check if user_url exist

Tags: php, wordpress, edit

In my function I have a check if email exist:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
        if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
            $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
        elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
            $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
        else{
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
        }
    }
```

but i can't figure out how to run the same check for the URL of the user profile field exists or not.
It can be done? If so, how?

Comment: I think you could use a combination of [`get_author_posts_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/) for the current user, and a [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_User_Query/prepare_query/), probably just through [`get_users`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)

Comment: What $_POST data are you passing to this function? How are you calling it?  Are you saying you're doing something like `$_POST['author_url']`, and you want to see if anyone else has the same URL in their profile?  Also, for whatever it's worth, you're processing post data but you're using `esc_attr` which is for output. You want to use `sanitize_email` instead before you pass it to the database.

Comment: This IF is inside a function in a custom page in the frontend.

There is a module for editing user data that recalls standard fields and custom items, address, mobile etc.

This function must update the user profile data in the backend (and DB) and then, in the case of user_url, email, username etc ... verify that they have not already been used by another user.

Comment: `email_exists` is an existing function WordPress provides, same as `username_exists` - those fields _need_ to be unique, hence WP provides functions to check that. There likely is no corresponding thing for a URL field though, so you would have to implement that yourself, if you need it. `get_users` with a meta query on the user URL field could be a quick way to do that.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks for the tip. I am not a developer but I will try to follow your advice.